# FacebookSDK Android 3.5.2 GraphApiSample: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I just download Android FacebookSDK 3.5.2 zip. And try to run GraphApiSample. 
I got the correct info when I request "/me".

But when I request "/me/friends?fields=name" I got the error:An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

I check the active session permissions: there are 'user_friends' and 'basic_info'.

Anyone could help me?

Penny
Tipcat Interactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the sample working.

Just replace /me/friends?fields=name to /23133XXX/friends?fields=name. The '**23133xxx**' is the active user's id.

I don't know why '/me' graph path can work, but '/me/friends?fields=name' can't work.

Penny

Tipcat Interactive.

Comment: '/me' graph path doesn't work for me either in GraphApiSample, I get that same error.